# How can I collect table row display == "none"?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have table row in `display:table-row` and `display:none`

I want to collect value `tablerow == "display: table-row"` and show just `display:table-row`  in console.log

but my code is not show anything because not meet the condition if

have any one can advice for my code ?

```js
tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    if (tr[i].style == "display:table-row") {
        console.log(tr[i])
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr style = "display:none">
    <td>Human</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style = "display:table-row">
    <td>Robot</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style = "display:table-row">
    <td>Robot</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tr[i].style` returns an Object. What you need to use is the display property. See the 'if' line.

```js
tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    if (tr[i].style.display == "table-row") {
        console.log(tr[i])
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr style = "display:none">
    <td>Human</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style = "display:table-row">
    <td>Robot</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style = "display:table-row">
    <td>Robot</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to the answer. You missed `.display` in the `if` condition, and I used `===` instead of `==`.

```js
tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    if (tr[i].style.display === "table-row") {
        console.log(tr[i])
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr style = "display:none">
    <td>Human</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style = "display:table-row">
    <td>Robot</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style = "display:table-row">
    <td>Robot</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("[style='display:table-row']")  
rows.forEach(row => {    
        console.log(row.getAttribute('style')) // display:table-row
})
</script>
```